# Spring is refusing to send a ResponseEntity but does not throw exceptions

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My POJO/data model:

```
public class CanResendResponse {
    @JsonProperty(value = "canResend")
    @NotEmpty
    public Boolean canResend;

    // getters, setters & ctors
}
```

My Spring Boot controller & method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/data/fizzes")
class FizzResource {
    @GetMapping(value = "{fizzId}/canResend")
    public void canResendVerifications(@PathVariable(value = "fizzId") String fizzId) {
        Fizz fizz = fizzRepository.findById(fizzId);
        Boolean canResend;

        System.out.println("Fizz name:" + fizz.getName());

        if(fizz.canResend()) {
            canResend = Boolean.TRUE;
        } else {
            canResend = Boolean.FALSE;
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<CanResendResponse>(new CanResendResponse(canResend), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://localhost:9200/v1/data/fizzes12345/canResend
```

When I run the curl command I don't see any exceptions/error on the server side and the curl completes without error but I **do not see** the expected HTTP response entity, like:

```
{
  "canResend" : "true"
}
```

However I *do* see the `Fizz name: Joe` message in STDOUT.

I've confirmed the same behavior in a browser (I punch `https://localhost:9200/v1/data/fizzes12345/canResend`) into a browser and the response/page is empty. **Any ideas as to what I can do to fix this?**

Comment: You never return anything from the method

Comment: Cut n paste error - please see my updates @shazin

Comment: How do you return something when the method signature is void? Do you even compile this before posting in Stackoverflow?

Comment: Hi @shazin this is actually written in Groovy and I'm re-writing my code in Java so I can paste it in here. Groovy allows this, Java doesn't. But since I know this is a mis-utilization of Spring here (on my part) I don't want to confused people with Groovy stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method has VOID return type. Try this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "{fizzId}/canResend")
public ResponseEntity canResendVerifications(@PathVariable(value = "fizzId") String fizzId) {
    Your method code goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public void canResendVerifications(@PathVariable(value = "fizzId") String fizzId) {
```

to

```
public ResponseEntity<> canResendVerifications(@PathVariable(value = "fizzId") String fizzId) {
```

... and make sure you `return` that `ResponseEntity`.